# What kind of sentence structure is this and what does it convey?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-structure

"Prepared as he was for many shocks, Professor Gaitonde had not expected this".

I have seen sentences with similar form before too, which begin with an adjective followed by "as+he/she/it/they/we/I/you+primary verb,which is followed the other part of the sentence separated by a comma.
So, what kind of sentence structure do these belong to ?

Comment: It conveys "Even though he was prepared for many shocks..."

Comment: "Prepared as he was for many shocks" is best analysed as a type of concessive adjunct. Note that "as" could be replaced by the concessive adverb "though"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'*Prepared*' is an adjective. '*Prepared for many shocks*' would be an adjective phrase describing Professor Gaitonde.

The clause '*as he was*' is an adverbial clause modifying the adjective within the adjective phrase.

I'm not aware of a name for this particular kind of sentence structure, it's just a different way of phrasing what could be written as:

> Professor Gaitonde had not expected this, *even though* he was prepared for many shocks.

Comment: A preferable analysis is one where the adjective "prepared" is a preposed complement in the preposition phrase "prepared as he was for many shocks" = "as he was prepared for many shocks".